# how to register click event in directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Im new in angularjs. I have a div #single I want to change the background color and then want to call back-end server on the click event. I dont know how to this in angularjs custom directive . any help will b appreciated 
my html code

```
 <div id="single" class="" ng-style="{'background':x.is_read == 0 ?
 'rgba(98, 95, 95, 0.87)': '#A4A4A4'}"  ng-repeat="x in notification"  chang-color>
```

changColor is directive that have following code . please help me how to do this

```
 var app = angular.module('smac', []);
 app.controller('asd',function ($http,$scope) { 

 app.directive("changColor", function() {

 return {
        restrict: 'A',
         scope: {},
         link: link
    };
        function link (scope, element) {
        element.on('click', onClick);
    }

    function onClick () {
        alert('as');
        $(this).css({ 'background': '#A4A4A4' });
   // after this back end call 
    }



    });
  });
```

Comment: The directive is creating an isolate scope which isolates the `notification` variable in the `ng-repeat`. Also the style changes in the custom directive compete with the `ng-style` directive.

Comment: you are saying I have already implementing ng-class and repeat directive on this so i cant do apply further directive ? @georgeawg

Comment: You can combine directives on the same element but you need to avoid having the scopes conflict. See [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API -- scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-).

Comment: so can you help me in registering a click event..

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `element.bind` instead of `element.on`.
Target element can be accessed via event target or simply this.

```
var app = angular.module('smac', []);

app.controller('asd',function ($http,$scope) {  
  // this is controller body
});

app.directive("changColor", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
     scope: {},
     link: link
  };

  function link(scope, element) {
    element.bind('click', onClick);
  }

  function onClick (e) {
    alert('as');
    // Following lines as equal
    e.target.style.background = "#A4A4A4"; 
    this.style.background = "#A4A4A4"; 
    angular.element(this).css("background","#A4A4A4");
    // after this back end call 
  }
});
```

Comment: Please see my updated code. Your directive is defined inside a controller. It should be defined outside as a separate angular component.

Comment: For the proof of directive's work check https://plnkr.co/edit/UwFfrpQc0py1RA7q90id

Comment: perhaps there may problem